# nginx returns json file with status code

Tags: json, nginx, http-status-codes

I am trying to make `Nginx` returns a static json file, and i did that using :

```
location /health{
   default_type "application/json";
   alias /etc/health.json;
}
```

and the json file contains :

```
{
  "status" : "up"
}
```

What i need to do, is to find a way to return a status code with the json file based on the content of the response.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i need to make some logic before returning the status is up or down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why nginx returns json file with status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400731/why-nginx-returns-json-file-with-status-code)

Comment: its a copy of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to run nginx as a reverse proxy and then use some web server to return the status code.

### Webserver

For example, here's a simple node server which does this:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = '/path/to/your/file.json';

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', (json) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(json);
    const statusCode = data.status === 'up' ? 200 : 503;
    response.writeHead(status, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    response.write(json);
  });
  response.end();
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, (e) => console.log(e ? 'Oops': `Server running on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Python2 example (with flask):

```
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask import Response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def health():
  contents = open('health.json').read()
  parsed = json.loads(contents)
  status = 200 if parsed[u'status'] == u'up' else 503
  return Response(
        response=contents,
        status=status,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
```

If you can't even install Flask, then you can use [simplehttpserver](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET). In that case, you'd probably end up customizing the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler to send your response.

### Nginx config

Your nginx config needs to contain a proxy_pass to your webserver

```
location /health {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-REAL-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

You can see a full example here: https://github.com/AnilRedshift/yatlab-nginx/blob/master/default.conf

Comment: thanks for the help, i though about this, but the problem i don't have any server on the VM, only nginx

Comment: Not even python 2? Many programming languages have a built-in webserver, or a easy library which does

Comment: You can forward the request to any URL you control, it doesn't have to be on the same box.

Comment: i do have python python2, can you please edit your code to match python2?